# Multiple config non writable errors after login on fresh install of Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, login

I was running 15.04 on my HP probook 640 G1 and all was running really well.  I decided to upgrade this evening due to that version not being supported any more.

I've installed 16.04.1 from live DVD and it installed without error.  Root folder is on one ext4 partition that was formatted during installation, I pointed /home at the other ext4 partition that my files are located on.

However, during log-in, I am bombarded with error messages (in the region of 50 different ones) about the config files.  This also happens when logged in when opening some applications.

For example opening Dolphin gives 
Configuration file "/home/grovehill/.config/dolphinrc" not writable.
Please contact your system administrator
&
Configuration file "/home/grovehill/.config/trash.sorc" not writable.
Please contact your system administrator.

I've run all updates and tried renaming the .config folder to .config.old to get the system to refresh the config, but no luck.

Any assistance gratefully received.
Thanks,
M

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be that you're getting disk access errors (check with `dmesg`) that then force the partition to be remounted as read-only, preventing any further writes and possibly corrupting the file system. This will happen if the 'errors=remount-ro' mount option is specified, e.g.

```
$ mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

Comment: How do I fix it?